# Repetition Structures - Starting Out With Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

In 'Starting Out With Python 3rd Edition' by Tony Gaddis, one of the solutions to an exercise is as follows:

```
character = '#'
numRows = 7
space = ' '

for row in range(numRows):
    for col in range(row + 2):
        if col == 0 or col == row + 1:
            print(character, end='')
        else:
            print(space, end='')
    print()
```

No one in my class understands how this solution works, **more specifically, the math in lines 6-7**. Could someone explain how each line results in an output of:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
#      #
```

Comment: What, specifically, don't you understand? Do you know what a `for` loop is? What the `range` function does? What the `==` operator is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row has one more whitespace than the previous. First iterates through the rows

```
for row in range(numRows):
```

then, for each row iterates through the columns that must print(# or whitespaces)

```
for col in range(row + 2):
```

Now, if the column is the first or the last prints the separator character (#)

```
if col == 0 or col == row + 1:
    print(character, end='')
```

The trick here is telling print that it shouldn't end in a newline (default behaviour) like in

```
print('one line')
print('another line')
```

If it's not the first or the last column just print a whitespace

```
else:
    print(space)
```

The last sentence is just to write the newline

```
print()
```

Comment: @Mr-E Could you further explain the math in lines 6-7?

Comment: Each row has `2 + number of row` (Row 0 -> 2 columns, row 1 -> 3 columns...). `range(row+2)` returns a list of numbers until `row+2` (`[0,1,2,... row+1]`, `row+2` not included), so in that list the first column is column 0 and the last one is row+1, in those cases you must print a `#` any other column is a whitespace